# Checking for isinstance gives weird error

Tags: python

I'm getting a strange error when I perform a isinstance call on an object in one of my functions:

```
def subtotals_to_decimal_string(obj):
    """
    Converts subtotals to decimal strings
    """
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for cr in obj:
            sub = cr['subtotal']
            cr['subtotal'] = Decimal(str(sub)).quantize(Decimal('0.01')).to_eng_string()
        return obj
```

The error I'm getting is similar to the one from this post:  http://bit.ly/MmkObr

The strange part is that I was able to execute this call in a separate python file.  What's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the error directly in your post.  SO questions should be as self-contained as possible, for the benefit of future readers of this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably, you have a global variable named `list`, which is shadowing the built-in name `list`.  Don't use names of built-in classes as variable names (or even better, no built-in names at all).

Comment: +1 This happens all the time sigh... I guess everybody has to experience it once.

Comment: No, it's not because of that.  But I'll accept your answer anyways.

Comment: @Mark: The error message you got is only possible if the name `list` does not point to a type object, which in turn means it does not point to its original value.  The details of how this comes about may slightly vary.